# Hiding popup window in parent window using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows

In my site registration is done by a step by step process.

In the first step I open a popup window using JavaScript and close this popup window automatically after the tasks in that window have been completed.

Next I go to the next step by clicking a button. There is another button in the second step to return back to first step.

When I come to the first step by clicking on back button in the second step the popup window in first step will loaded.

It does not need to load this pop up window when return back to first step.

How can I do this?

This is the JavaScript code :

```
function show_gal()
{

    var windowSizeArray = [ "width=935,height=580",
                                    "width=935,height=600,scrollbars=yes" ];
    var url1 = "<?php echo base_url();?>plugin/index.php";
    var id = $("#hidtuid").val();
    var url = url1+"?usrid=" + id;
    var windowName = "Image Upload";
    var windowSize = windowSizeArray;
    window.open(url, windowName, windowSize);
}
```

This is the code in popup window after completing the task in popup window:

```
window.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Its more a logical question, you will find different ways to do this. One way is:

Are you loading  the first window on page load?

If so use a hidden variable in your first page when ever first popup is closed assign some value to the hidden feild.

On your page load function before calling the popup check the value of this hidden feild if it is not assigned you will not show the popup.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
window.parent.close();
```